# VB .net Background image goes black when resizing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, background, fullscreen

I am creating  program and have to make it look pretty as it will be displayed on plamsas around the building.

I created the background image as jpg size 1920 x1024
Ive imported into resources and set that as the background in format stretch

However if i use code to make the app full screen the areas previously not shown are black however I have a transparent picture box and the back ground showns from under that but not the rest.

However there are no objects where the areas are black

My screen resoution is 1920 x 1024

[Back Ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwJLl.jpg)

Comment: *plamas*  I need to get me some of that

Comment: Yes it's a bug. Put background load image code in a Form Resize event